# How to specify text even more?

Tags: selector, playwright

I would like to know if there is a way to specify the text selection even more than `text="text"`? Specification of playwright is no enough, and moreover I cannot use other selectors due to the structure of tests (there are more than several thousands of assertions, so I make custom commands)

The problem is the following: on the web page that I am testing there are several pieces of text locators, all of which contain the same text fragment. For example when I use `"'The Exact text'"` I get selectors with text `'The Exact text'` and `'Some Other TextThe Exact text'`.

Answer (score 2):

https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#text-selector

You could use JavaScript regex to get what You need as it is stated in documentation here are few examples:

`/Log\s*in/i` - body can be a JavaScript-like regex wrapped in / symbols. For example, `text=/Log\s*in/i` matches Login and log IN.

```
await page.click('text=/Log\\s*in/i');
```

Or Use text-matches:

`#nav-bar :text-matches("reg?ex", "i")` - the `:text-matches()` pseudo-class can be used inside a css selector, for regex-based match. This example is equivalent to text=/reg?ex/i, but inside the #nav-bar element.

To get exact match of text use:

```
await page.locator(':text-is("The Exact text")')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem is the following: on the web page that I am testing there are several pieces of text locators, all of which contain the same text fragment. For example when I use `"'The Exact text'"` I get selectors with text `'The Exact text'` and `'Some Other TextThe Exact text'` and that is a problem I am trying to solve. I use locator function, maybe it is better to use elementHandles and evaluate?

Comment: You can use eval on locator which is recommended. To get exactli what You want use:
`await page.locator(':text-is("The Exact text")')`

Comment: @senaid Your comment should be a a part of your answer. It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `first()` should be enough to assert the test.

`await expect(page.locator('text="The Exact Text"').first()).toBeVisible();`